# IntelliJ no longer reacts to CTRL-C to interrupt terminal processes

Tags: powershell, intellij-idea

For the last 2 month or so IntelliJ (Ultimate) no longer responds to CTRL-C interrupts.
I use powershell as integrated terminal (tried all other available terminals as well), and no luck.

If I use powershell separately (so not the integrated terminal) it works just fine...

My current workaround is closing the terminal tab and run the command again.

These are my terminal settings:
[image: terminal settings]

Anyone has any clue?

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: @y.bedrov while preparing for this I tried it again, and still failed. But because I wanted to give a minimal log, I exited intellij and renamed the current log file to get a fresh one on start up. And somehow now it works again.... if you put this in an answer I am more then willing to accept it as solution!

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't look like good solution :) Let's leave it as a comment.